# CSS positioning

Tags: css, positioning

I have a table to get new password and confirm password . And div called "error" which is hidden/display block. When i am validating the inputs, I am showing this div when validation fails.

This makes other elements to re-align their positions. Suppose I am placing some elements above the image, and when the div is displayed, those elements come out image.

What is the correct way to do?

I tried Positioning (relative, absolute) . But of no use.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: this is the normal behavior. Without some code, we cannot advise on specifics.

Answer (score 2):

You should use css `visiblity:hidden` and `visibility:visible` style attributes, this will ensure that it takes its required space even though it is hidden.

using `display:block` or `display:none` will take required space or no space respectively, this is what causes the unpredictable realignment of the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in css,
`<div id="outer" style="position:absolute">
  <div id="inner" style="position:relative">
  </div>
</div>`

means outer should be `absolute` and the inner divs be `relative`.
In your case, I would suggest to go for `position: fixed`, since it is a error message block.